# How to make a dropdown for time input field in Orbeon forms CE

Tags: orbeon

I created a form. It is having time inputs and date inputs. Date input is working fine. I can choose the date from dropdown. But time can't be selected through dropdown. There is no dropdown working at time input. Only tome icon is showing. I want to have a dropdown for time inputs as date inputs.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you post you code, what have you done so far :)

Comment: I created a form. It is having both Date and Time input fields.. I can select the date through drop down at Date input field. But I can't select time from drop down clock or something..It is just to be write in the filed..Only clock icon is appearing. when click on that nothing happens. I want a drop down clock or something to select the time easily without typing..

Comment: post the html code bro

Comment: I did not code. I just used the orbeon forms..No need to code.. i created a form with tools which they have given.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that at time of this writing, Orbeon Forms doesn't come out-of-the-box with a control that allows users to select a time through dropdowns on a desktop browser. So for now users will have to type the time in a text field.

- On mobile browsers, you'll get the equivalent of dropdowns on that platform (iOS or Android), as shown in the screenshots on this [very old blog post on the topic](https://blog.orbeon.com/2011/11/orbeon-forms-now-using-native.html).
- On desktop browsers, this is covered by request for enhancement [#4252](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4252).